# Disable sure-fire and execute fail-safe report to run my test cases in a Maven project

Tags: maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

In my parent POM I have configured for sure fire report. But in some modules, I need to skip the sure fire report generation and instead I want to run fail-safe plugin to generate the test report.

I have tried like

```xml
<properties>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    <skipFailsafeTests>false</skipFailsafeTests>
</properties>


      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skipFailsafeTests}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>

            <skipExec>${skipTests}</skipExec>
            <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
       </plugin>
```

But still it seems sure-fire report is running. Is there any way to overcome it?

Comment: You are using really old versions of failsafe plugin ? up-to-date version is 2.12...

Comment: What i don't understand why you need to disable the reporting in some modules, cause surefire is for unit tests where failsafe is for integration tests so why deactivating/activating ? Does not make sense to me.

Comment: I need to add some more details in the test report in 'verify' phase. if we are using surefire, it wont invoke 'verify' phase, if any test failure occurred. That's why I have gone with fail-safe plugin.